# Isn't "fluctuations of the order parameter" a wrong terminology in here?

Tags: field-theory, phase-transition

In the book *Statistical Field Theory* by Giuseppe Mussardo, on page 11, it is given that

> Aspects of phase transitions. It is now useful to stop and highlight the aspects of phase transitions that have emerged so far. The most important property is that at $T=T_{c}$, the **fluctuations of the order parameter** extend significantly to the entire system, while they are exponentially small away from the critical point.

However, what do they mean by "fluctuations of the order parameter"?

To my understanding, what extends to the entire system is the correlation length, not the fluctuations in the order parameter. I mean, when one says "fluctuations", to me, it refers to something related to the variance of the random variable in question. But that is not the case, so I'm confused

Comment: Think about what the magnetisation looks like in the Ising model at criticality.

Comment: @jacob1729 I'm thinking about that, and the thing that extends over the entire system is the correlation length, not something else

Comment: @Our The correlation length is a measure of the distance over which **fluctuations in the magnetization** are correlated, is it not?

Comment: @J.Murray yes, indeed, but "fluctuations" and "extending" doesn't go well together in terms of linguistics, and that makes me question whether I am getting everything correctly.

Comment: @Our I'm not really sure what you mean.  A fluctuation could be extremely well-localized - involving points only within a small spatial neighborhood of each other - or it could extend over the entire system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correlation length is defined in terms of the distance dependence of the correlation of the order parameter fluctuations at different points.
$$
G(r) = \langle \delta m(r+r') ~\delta m(r') \rangle\propto \frac{e^{-r/\xi}}{r}.
$$
Divergence of the correlation length $\xi$ implies long-range correlations requiring long-range fluctuation of the order parameter.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you mean by "long-range fluctuation of the order parameter"? I still don't understand what people refer to by this terminology

Comment: @Our A function decaying like $1/r$ is long-range: in $3D$ it is non-integrable. More in general, a function in $D$ dimensions is considered long-range (for statistical mechanics) if the  D-dimensional space integral of the asymptotic part is diverging.